# I was trying to solve a Leetcode problem, regarding identifying if the number entered is a palindrome or not

Tags: java, palindrome

I understood the logic behind the problem's solution, but in the coded solution I am a bit confused about the return statement in the end. Please explain to me what is its significance, why is it being used, etc ? (not why return is used but why is that value being returned).

```
class Solution {
public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
    // 2 cases  x < 0 = false case 
    //  x > 0 = test case
    
    if (x < 0 || x % 10 == 0 && x != 0){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        int newNum = 0;
        while (x > newNum){
        int r = (x % 10);
        newNum = newNum * 10 + r;
        x /= 10;
        }
    //the part I am confused about - below     
    return x == newNum || x == newNum / 10;
    }
   
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to understand the Logic for the return statement let us take 2 numbers

1. **1234321**
2. **678876**

So one thing here While loop is doing is to create a new number(newNum) out of X and making sure that newNum stores the reverse of X till the middle point.

So in case of **1234321** , this while loop will execute till X=123 and newNum=1234.

After exiting out from while loop with these values, out of the 2 statements in return, x == newNum / 10 will give true result hence return statement will return true.which means the number is palindrome.

**Please note here that the no. digits in given integer is odd(7)**

Let us now Take other example **678876**

In this case when the while loop ends, the value for the X would be 678 and newNum would be 678

out of the 2 statements in return, x == newNum this time will give true result hence return statement will return true again .which means the number is palindrome.

**Please note here that the no. digits in given integer is even(6)**

All in all, this statement  return x == newNum || x == newNum / 10;
is to make sure that **we are covering the condition for both Odd and even no. of digits in the given integer X**.

Comment: Ah I see, Now I completely understand it. It seems I got confused by the explanation that was given there. Now I understand it fully, Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Glad it helped !